# How to update columns based on another column

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I would like to know how to update the information of one column based on another column

My example looks like

```
df <- data.frame(input = c("Teline stenopetala", "Teline stenopetala", 
                           "Teline stenopetala", "Prunus lusitanica", "Prunus lusitanica"),
                 n1 = c("Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.", NA, NA, NA, "Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd."))
```

The `df` includes the `input` column, and the 'n1' column whose values correspond to the `input` column's value.

I would want to call in the event that I find any duplicated rows in the `input` column, the values that are blank in `n1` will be modified according to the value that is already present in `n1` associated with the value of the `input` column.

Let's say the data is big so I would not want to call specific-name e.g. using `df %>% mutate(n1 = case_when(input == "Teline stenopetala" ~ "..."`

My desired output here:

```
df <- data.frame(input = c("Teline stenopetala", "Teline stenopetala", 
                           "Teline stenopetala", "Prunus lusitanica", "Prunus lusitanica"),
                 n1 = c("Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.", "Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.", "Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.", "Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd.", "Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd."))
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd like to apply `fill(n1, .direction = "downup")` on grouped dataframe. Check the last example on `?tidyr::fill` ( https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` and `fill` downup as also suggested by @margusl, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(input) %>%
  fill(n1, .direction = "downup")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
# Groups:   input [2]
  input              n1                                 
  <chr>              <chr>                              
1 Teline stenopetala Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.
2 Teline stenopetala Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.
3 Teline stenopetala Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.
4 Prunus lusitanica  Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd.      
5 Prunus lusitanica  Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
df <- data.frame(input = c("Teline stenopetala", "Teline stenopetala", 
                           "Teline stenopetala", "Prunus lusitanica", "Prunus lusitanica"),
                 n1 = c("Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.", NA, NA, NA, "Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd."))

library(dplyr , warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df %>% group_by(input) %>% 
  mutate(n1 = n1[which(!is.na(n1))])

#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#> # Groups:   input [2]
#>   input              n1                                 
#>   <chr>              <chr>                              
#> 1 Teline stenopetala Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.
#> 2 Teline stenopetala Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.
#> 3 Teline stenopetala Genista stenopetala Webb & Berthel.
#> 4 Prunus lusitanica  Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd.      
#> 5 Prunus lusitanica  Prunus hixa Brouss ex. Willd.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>